# how to disable a tab in android screen?

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs

hi can you tell me how to disable a tab in the UI of android code.. (eclair code)

Comment: did you check the android documentation ? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html#setEnabled(boolean)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you mean to disable one tab button on TabWidget, then try this code:

```
// tabHost = ... (get TabHost)
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(your_index).setEnabled(false);
```

If you want to disable tab widget in overall, then:

```
// tabWidget = ... (get TabWidget)    
tabWidget.setEnabled(false);
```

Read SDK Help for references:

- [TabHost](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html)
- [TabWidget](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html)

Comment: setEnabled(false) doesn't seem to prevent the tab from being clicked on and selected.
It does though trigger the disabled style on it.

Comment: why I have to use tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(index).setClickable(false) ?

Comment: @micahli123 Who talks about `setClickable()`? Can you explain your question? I don't understand it. Why you have to use `setClickable()`, or `tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(index)`, or anything else?

Comment: @Sergey Glotov I want to disable the tab button. But I tried the method you talked. It doesn't not work for me. Then I replace setEnable to setClickable. Then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Extend TabHost and override methods:

```
@Override
public void setCurrentTab(int currentTab) {
    if (currentTab != 2)  // position of the tab that should not get selected
        super.setCurrentTab(currentTab);
    else
        // in my case I want to trigger something here but I don't want the button to get selected
}

@Override
public void setCurrentTabByTag(String tag) {
    if (!"\"plus_tab\"".equals(tag))  // tag of the tab that should not get selected
        super.setCurrentTabByTag(tag);
    else
        // in my case I want to trigger something here but I don't want the button to get selected
}
```