# android.support.design.widget.TabLayout select Tab Programmatically

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am using android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.
It has two tabs,
If user selects second tab On particular condition I want user to redirect to first tab and disallow him to go to sencond tab until condition matches.
To achieve this I tried,

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
```

but it does not reselect first tab

Comment: Rather than allowing them to navigate and then having to redirect them, it may be easier to disable tab selection until the criteria are met: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497187/how-to-disable-a-tab-in-android-screen

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon , thanks,
But example in your link is related to TabHost.It has setEnable() methode in tabhost.getTabwidget.
I am using new TabLayout in support library.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is because that view is still not **initialized** properly, and you are trying to perform some action.

As a solution you just need to put one **hadler before selecting perticular tab**.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(
    new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(yourTabIndex).select();
        }
}, 100);
```

Comment: is there any possibility to listen for an event (i.e. onCreationComplete) .. so that implement an event based solution, instead of using hard coded timer?

Comment: I guess there is no such method for that.

Comment: I think I solved it without the hardcoded timer, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51232942/2299005)

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved it:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(CurrentItem).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
int tabIndex = 2;
tabLayout.setScrollPosition(tabIndex,0f,true);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(tabIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the tab in `Fragment.onViewCreated()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my setup. works fine for me.

```
      //declare your tabs to be add on
        TabLayout tlDailyView;
        private TabLayout.Tab tabAppointment, tabSlots;


    @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_daily_view, container, false);
            initializeMembers();
            setupTabLayout();
            return view;
        }


    private void setupTabLayout() {
            tlDailyView.addTab(tabAppointment, 0, true);
            tlDailyView.addTab(tabSlots, 1, true);
            tlDailyView.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                        case 0:
                        //open fragment at position 0 here
                        case 1:
                        //open fragment at position 1 here
                            break;
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });
        }

 private void initializeMembers() {
        tabSlots = tlDailyView.newTab();
        tabAppointment = tlDailyView.newTab();
        tabAppointment.setText(R.string.tab_appts).select();
        tabSlots.setText(R.string.tab_slots);
    }
```

don't forget to initialize your tab layout above.

Answer (score 0):

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(index specific).select();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but it might help other developers.

If you go inside and see how `tabLayout.getTabAt(tabIndex).select();` has been implemented inside. You'll come to know that, it sends your flow to

```
onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?)
```

and your flow doesn't go to

`onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?)`

if your **current tab** and **tabIndex** are same. So this is very important to consider.

Answer (score -1):

Mihir's answer gave me an idea to try this. Seems like it works without the hardcoded timer, and also correctly updates the scroll for selected tab:

```
final TabLayout tabLayout = ...;
tabLayout.postOnAnimation(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).select();
    }
});
```