# Android tabs - Disable switching between tabs on click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

How can I disable switching between tabs when user presses on them?

I use ViewPager and then polute it with tabs. I managed to disable swiping by using following code, but this doesn't prevent user from switching between tabs by clicking on them:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to disable a tab in android screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497187/how-to-disable-a-tab-in-android-screen)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout' then check this link [TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702725/android-disable-tablayout)

or if you using the old TabHost method then check this link [TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497187/how-to-disable-a-tab-in-android-screen)