# android disable 2 of 3 tabs

Tags: android, tabs

in my android app, i set an tab layout like this:

```
final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB 1"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB 2"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB 3"));
```

i would like to disable tab 2 and tab 3.
i try this and it works:

```
tabLayout.getChildAt(1).setEnabled(false);
tabLayout.getChildAt(2).setEnabled(false);
```

but i also would like to set an toast feedback, if somebody tap on a disable tab, like "This Tab is not unlocked"

for this i try to set an onclicklistener for tab 2 and 3.
but this listener doesn't work, if I disable the tab with the code before.

have anybody an idea how i can solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
                    tab1.select();
                } else {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can't receive the click event when a View is disabled. Try with TouchListener instead. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17836095/4224337) you can find an example how to detect click event in TouchListener.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497187/how-to-disable-a-tab-in-android-screen

Comment: i try now another way. please look the update part of my first post. i works fine. but the problem is, that i have to set the tab indicator back to tab 1. is there an way?

Comment: @SpecialFighter I'm getting tabLayout.getChildCount() always as 1 irrespective of how many Tabs I add. Any idea why?

Answer (score 6):

My TabLayout looks like the following

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tab1" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tab2" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tab3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tab3" />

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

You must cast the tabs you want to disable as view objects. Like this

```
View tab = ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(desiredPosition);
```

then you can change the clickability and set the alpha so that the tabs you want visually and functionally are enable or disable. in this way

```
ViewGroup tabItem = ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(desiredPosition);
    if (isChecked) {
        tabItem.setClickable(false);
        tabItem.setAlpha( 0.3F);
    }else {
        tabItem.setClickable(true);
        tabItem.setAlpha( 1F);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it is possible using disable and enable tab view but i have another way.

While user will click on the tab set flag like

```
if(enable != true)
// display toast
else
// enable event
```