# How to change the selected tab in a tabLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a tab layout with a view pager and 5 different tabs, if the user is not registered only one option is available, so I want to disable the click on the other tabs. What I did is override the onTabSelected to change the current item in the viewPager.

```
 @Override
  public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
     if (User.current != null) {
       viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
     } else {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
     }
  }
```

It works perfectly but it has one problem, the tab indicator change to the selected tab, so I want to keep the tab indicator on the first tab.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4497230/5598783) is what you're looking for.